# Can You Find Something Mod 2Pi in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

EDIT: I have an angle from using `Math.atan2()` which I then want to add or subtract values from. However, this addition and subtraction sometimes means the angle is greater that π or less than -π and I'm looking for a way to get one of these outside angles back into the correct range.

I'm trying to find a value mod 2π in JavaScript using the following code:

```
foo % Math.PI * 2;
```

However, it always just returns foo, even if I try this:

```
var bar = Math.PI * 2;
foo % bar;
```

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work?

Comment: pi % 2*pi is NOT -pi.  It is pi.  Modulo is defined as the remainder after division.  If you divide pi by 2pi, the result is 0 with a remainder of pi.  This remainder is your modulo result.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Maybe we can help you find what you are really looking for.

Comment: Added context in question, sorry for the poor way in which I asked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't making an assignment:

```
foo = foo % (Math.PI * 2);
```

Or:

```
foo %= Math.PI * 2;
```

EDIT:

To paraphrase your updated question, you have a value foo, which may be any angle, however you want foo to be in the range [-pi,pi].  You need to do this programatically:

```
foo %= 2 * Math.PI;  // Now in the range [-2pi,2pi]

if (Math.abs(foo) > Math.PI) {
  foo -= 2 * Math.PI * Math.sign(foo);
}
```

Comment: Even when I make an assignment, it still doesn't work. I still get the same value.

Comment: You will have to show more code then.  Both examples in use here: http://jsfiddle.net/4sFmN/

Comment: Oh sorry, I should rephrase my question. Is there any way I can get foo mod 2pi if it is less that 2pi (return a negative value)?

Comment: If foo is less than 2pi, the value returned will be foo.  That is how mod works.  You will only get a negative value when foo is < 0.

Comment: To mod by 2PI,  use `foo = foo % (Math.PI * 2);`, not `foo = foo % Math.PI * 2;`

Comment: @danh 12 years later... you are correct.  I missed the parens in the explicit example.  The compound examples still work, given the order of operations for compound operators.

Answer (score -1):

Types. Math.Pi is a double. Any (Int % Double) will return the Int side.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var bar = parseInt(Math.PI * 2 * 10000);
 document.write(bar / 10000 + "<br/>");
 var foo = 60000;
 foo %= bar;
 document.write(foo / 10000 + "<br />");
</script>
```

Comment: JS has no concept of Ints. The primitive number type is an IEEE 754 double.